# Electric company supply single-phase or 3-phase?

Tags: three-phase, phase, single-phase

Does the electrical company generally only supply single-phase in residential areas? i.e.: is 3-phase generally only available in higher use areas? And when 3-phase is supplied, do they have separate lines with single-phase as well?

Comment: That depends on location. Some houses may have only one phase connected, some may have all three.

Comment: I'm in New Zealand. My home has two phases supplied and at one stage had 3. This is unusual but not unknown. I have two meters, one for each phase,  with half the house supplied from one phase and one from the other.

Comment: This really depends on location. In germany the majority of houses get 3 phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the electrical company, supplies three-phase power voltage. A house is fed from one of these phases and the neutral, moreover, different houses in the same area are connected to different phases, but SHARE NEUTRAL.
The number of connected houses are arranged such that each phase has a load similar to the rest, that is, the load is balanced for the three-phase system.

There are other systems, such as two-phase (two phases and a neutral) but are of limited application in the world.

Comment: So... 3-phase is distributed as 4-wire 120° apart along with neutral/ground? But how does the single-phase get it's opposite 180° red wire along with the neutral?

Comment: @ericx If the voltage distribution is high (> 13200 Vac), three-phase 3-wire system is used. The 4-wire system (with neutral) is available at the user level, from the step-down transformer. High voltage is used in long-distance distribution.

Comment: @ericx The neutral represents the reference level for the phase voltage, i.e. **there's not** a 180º relation between phase and neutral. Or maybe I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: No, not to neutral. But when the single-phase is brought into the house, it comes on two hot wires (red and black down here) with 180° separation and the neutral on a third wire (white).

Comment: @ericx I understand. That sounds a biphasic (two phase) distribution system. It is not a system used worldwide (like 3 phase system), but obviously, there are places where it is applied.

Comment: @ericx The two x 180 degree phase voltages (from effectively a centre tapped single phase transformer winding) is used in the US and no doubt elsewhere but is unknown in many countries. eg I'm in NZ and it's not used here.

Comment: I'm in Massachusetts, US and I have been told that we have 3-phase distribution (at least on the main roads). Can you pull that 180° off a step-down? (I've also always wondered why it's called single-phase and not double-phase.)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I work in a firm that manufactures equipment including all types of power transformers. I remember a design of a transformer with windings connected in delta, where one of these windings has a center tap connected to neutral. I guess that kind of transformer is to generate the distribution system to which you refer.

Comment: @ericx There is called _Scott_ assembly which allows a two-phase power from a three-phase network. You can see it at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott-T_transformer

Comment: @ericx:  The step-down transformer feeding your house will only get power from one of the three high voltage phases.  The step-down transformer has a 240V centre-tapped secondary (a 240V winding with a connection in the middle, as well as two connections at the ends of the winding).  The centre tap is grounded and becomes the "neutral".  The two end connections on the transformer are the two "hot" wires to your house.  There will be 120V from either hot wire to the neutral, and 240V between the two hot wires.

Answer (score 1):

In my area (Vancouver BC), 3-phase high voltage lines run north along the street at the end of my block.  In each lane (running east/west) a single high voltage line connected to one of the 3-phase lines provides power to single phase transformers that step the high voltage down to 120/240 to feed several houses.  Successive lanes get different phases in order to keep the phase loading balanced.

In a commercial area, all three high voltage phases will run along the lane feeding 3-phase step-doen transformers, so most commercial users will have 3-phase 120/208V power.

Very large commercial or industrial customers may even have their own substation providing 3-phase power at a moderate voltage, with transformers throughout the site to step that down to 120/208.

Comment: 120/208 is actually pretty rare. Most medium to large customers will be using 480 V or 600 V 3-phase power for large loads, and 120/240V single-phase for plug-in loads.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Where I worked, I'm pretty sure we had 120/208 as the general AC power in shops and offices.

Comment: @PeterBennett - In the office I work in (California), the feed is 480V 3 phase. The lighting is fed directly off of that as 3 groups of 277V. Then there are two step-down transformers (one in the electrical room and one in the lab) producing 120V and 208V for plug-in equipment. 277V lighting is very common in offices since they reduce the load on the step-down transformers.